# impresspages free theme licence, remove backlinks?

Tags: themes, impresspages

I am deciding to make a page with impresspages. I want to ask if i am allowed to remove footer information of free templates. In drupal CMS this is legal, but i know, on some CMS the authors of free themes want to keep "back links" in their free work. 
Many thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know none of current ImpressPages 4 themes require you to leave any links. But each theme might have its own comments. So please double check just in case.

Hope you are considering this option because it is really important to you. As those links help us grow.